Elastic Search CCR Issue
I have two elastic search instances hosted on different aws regions and they both are secured via basic authentication. Is there any way for enabling Cross Cluster replication between both of them I have looked after each and every aspect and even in the elastic search documentation i haven't got anything?
I tried to connect via Elastic search ccr by enabling the licensce from trial to gold
Whitelisted both the ip's and also provided full access to both the instance ip's in both the instances security group
Tried via the instance terminal via curl to connect
Persisent volume was connected but saying false at the end
Enabled vpc peering as well
